# slick2.0: how to transport the TableQuery object into the template?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, slick

I am new learner of slick.

I make a model:

```
class Page(tag:Tag) extends Table[(Long,Int, String,String,String, Long, Long, String)](tag, "Page"){
  def id=column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def subid=column[Int]("subject")
  def title=column[String]("Title", O.NotNull)
  def describe=column[String]("Describe")
  def profile=column[String]("Profile")
  def icon=column[Long]("icon")
  def resource=column[Long]("Picture")
  def url=column[String]("Out_link")
  def * = (id, subid,title, describe, profile,icon, resource, url)
}
val page=TableQuery[Page]
```

I want transport the variable page into my playframework2.2 page_list.scala.html, I do not know how to transport the variable into playframwork template, the 'page' is the Object not class

```
(sublist: TableQuery)(implicit request: Request[Any])
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 @for(eachsubject <- sublist){
           .....         
                    }
<div class="element">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to get the each element in TableQuery and then use another template to present them.
ps: anyone know some more complex example with slick2.0 and playframework the official give just so naive, even do not transport the TableQuery elements.

Answer (score 0):

You probably only want to transfer the result of a query, not the TableQuery object, which just resembles a query fetching the while table. To get the result just call

`page.run` which is then of type `Seq[(Long,Int, String,String,String, Long, Long, String)]`.

That may actually be more advanced than you need, but it is absolutely possible to pass around the TableQuery object, but you probably would want to pass around `Query` instead, which is a super type. See the talk 2013-12-03 PATTERNS FOR SLICK DATABASE APPLICATIONS AT SCALA EXCHANGE 2013 at http://slick.typesafe.com/docs/ .